# Get stable range in google spreadsheets (after adding/deleting rows in that range)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Having a problem with a range of cells.
On the list first 2 rows are headers and rows 3-82 (80 total) are for data.
I have to delete/add rows from this data sometimes and my condition formating rules and formulas are changing.

E.x. `=COUNTIF(WIN!B3:B78; "<>")` had range `B3:B82`, but after deleting of rows it became as `B3:B78`.

Any way to hardcode this 82 value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX` function:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:INDEX(B:B,82), "<>")
```

Comment: Thank you!
Working with `=COUNTIF(WIN!B3:INDEX(WIN!B:B;82); "<>")` for my case with other page